# Symfony 3: Unable to find template

Tags: php, symfony

I've created an entity with [`generate:doctrine:entity`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html) and its controller too with [`generate:doctrine:crud`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html).

All works well on local, but on the server I receive this error:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException:
>   "Unable to find template "entity/index.html.twig"

And the error is right, as there is no template for the entity and its actions.

But my question is: why on local Symfony "guesses" the template and anyway arranges a page while on remote it doesn't?

This error should appear also on local, why it isn't?

Comment: do you have deployed all the files on the server ?

Comment: Yes, for sure... I have no changes in commit: all files are committed and deployed.

Comment: Try again `git add --all` and commit. Please would you post the `controller:action` you execute when you have this issue ?

Comment: -.-' A simple `git status` showed untracked files. This is the reason why I didn't see changes in the files when committing. Excuse me. A very stupid error.

Comment: Then do you have `push` the `commit`?

Comment: Not yet... I'm going to...